# google closure compiler and json

Tags: javascript, json, google-closure-compiler

I have a json string that I parse and then access the properties of the object with the dot notation. However, in the google closure compiler, the dot notation (`MyObject.PropertyName`) gives warning that the property isn't defined.

For now, the solution I'm using is to convert my code into bracket notation (`MyObject['PropertyName']`). This removes the warning but also prevents the compiler from doing its job. On the other hand, when I write `JSON.stringify(MyObject)`, the server receives a string with property names that are understandable.

So my question is how do we best use the google compiler in advanced mode when working with json objects that are deserialized and serialized at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only JavaScript you are going to write is accessing external json, then it defeats the point of using the compiler. However, if you have even a trivial amount of JavaScript which does work besides parsing your json into domain models then the compiler may be useful.

In our parsers we access our data via bracket notation so we can get the data properly. From there we stuff the data into our own models, which we use the . notation on. These get wildly renamed, gives us type checking and all of that goodness.

Edit>>
For data I use the [XHRManager](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_net_XhrManager.html). This is one seriously nice class. When I get a data event from that pool I handle it as follows.

```
/**
 * @private
 * @param {goog.events.Event} evt The event recieved from the XhrIo.
 */
mypath.MyClass.prototype.onDataRecieved_ = function(evt) {
  if (evt.type != 'complete') return;
  var xhrIo = evt.target;
  var data = xhrIo.getResponseJson();
  //do somethign!
};
```

I have to warn you, my XHRManager handling still leaves a fair bit to be desired. I only refactored my code last week to start using it.

For parsing I do this: (This is some raw stuff from my code base, so ignore some of the ugly.)

```
our.class.path.ContestJsonParser.prototype.setContestProperties =
    function(contest, element) {
  contest.setName(element['description']);
  /**
     * @type {!number}
     */
  var timeAsInt = element['startTime'];
  contest.setScheduledStartTime(timeAsInt);
  var clockModel = contest.getClockModel();
  if (goog.isDefAndNotNull(element['period'])) {
    clockModel.setMatchState(element['period']['periodName']);
    clockModel.setStateStartTime(element['period']['periodStartTime']);
  }
  //TODO (Johan) this needs to change today to consider the rest of the stats
  //information
  var stats = element['statistics'];
  if (goog.isObject(stats) && goog.isDefAndNotNull(stats['score'])) {
    var score = stats['score'];
    contest.setMatchScore(score['home'], score['away']);
  } else {
    contest.setMatchScore(undefined, undefined); // clears score.
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you constantly serialize your data via json.stringify and json.parse? this is extremely inefficient, what is your reason for doing this. My code won't make a ton of sense to you out of context, but we seperate model creation from parsing by using the builder pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern. I honestly think the core of your problem might be your use of stringify + parse, explain to me what you are aiming to solve with this.

Comment: Yes, I use native serializer. What's a better option? I read somewhere that using a library is slower than using a native parse. The objects come and go via ajax and also to and from local storage.

Comment: I just ammended my comment, check again and explain to me why you use Json.stringify and Json.parse the whole time.

Comment: How do you handle the transport in ajax? At some point, the data is in json and so for the moment, I have to parse the strings. I'd be nice if you could show with some code what it looks like when avoiding JSON.parse; even for an object with just 2 properties. There's no good explanation on how to use typedef and json parsing together.

Comment: ok, where in the code is the cast from a generic json object to a javascript object with typed definition?

Comment: re your previous question, the contest model is an explicitly typed object

Comment: what would the code look like if it were? I wish someone would write a blog post on strongly typed google compiler usage with json

Comment: as i said before you create a strongly typed model and parse the data into that, you put a lot of checks in between (all those goog.isDefAnd... goog.isArray...) and from there you deal with a typed model.I gave you all the bits apart from the model here. I would recomend reading this as well https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Uq_vNyPZjlRvYZJclX6N37Fjsiah4XNciEPSBfFiREs/edit

Answer (score 5):

You basically have two choices:

1. use object array access using the string literal (aka `MyJsonObject['PropertyName']`) this is the simple solution.
2. create a extern file describing the properties in your JSON object and then use dot notation (aka `MyJsonObject.PropertyName`).  This requires more maintenance but allows the compiler to type check the properties if you provide type annotations in your extern description.

Comment: Do you have any resources that I can look at for specifying externs files? thanks!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3?hl=en#externs   

Generally, externs must be valid javascript, but simplified declarations:
var

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** the `@expose` directive has been deprecated

---

> **Google Closure Compiler** lets you specify directives on how compilation should be done through **annotations**.
>
> See:
>   https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler
>
> Properly using **@expose** and **@type** you can preserve the name of
>   a property in your code.
>
> It is possible to safely decode a JSON string into an object and
>   access that object using the dot notation. You'll be also able to
>   stringify back the data.
>
> -
>
> Let's make an example:
>
> You want to parse an array of objects. Every object represents a
>   "size", with the properties **w** for width and **h** for height.
>
> Declare a prototype for the **size** object and *expose* its
>   properties **w** and **h**
>
> ```
> function size() {}
>
> /** @expose */
> size.prototype.w = 0;
> /** @expose */
> size.prototype.h = 0;
> ```
>
> Then you want to put the JSON parsed data into an array called
>   **data**.
>
> Using **@type** you declare that **data** is going to hold an
>   **array** of object of type **size**.
>
> ```
> function main()
> {
>     /** @type {Array.<size>} */
>     var data;
>
>     // string built up just for example purposes
>     var response = '[{"w": 10, "h": 20}]';
>
>     // parse the array
>     var data = JSON.parse(response);
>
>     // access data with dot notation!
>     console.log(data[0].w+ "    "+ data[0].h);
> }
>
> main();
> ```

Comment: I can't find any mention of `@expose` on the web page you point to.  Is this annotation documented somewhere?

Comment: @jochen the `@expose` directive has been removed from the documentation. Surprisingly is not even mentioned as deprecated. It seems now `@expose` appears only on some SO answers, like mine. I guess it is still supported to avoid breaking legacy code but I didn't check. I'm still using an old version of the Closure Compiler (from a time `@expose` was documented and implemented)

Comment: `@expose` is now officially deprecated.